# How Can I Send Value From onPostExecute() to Activity

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, textview, httprequest

First of all I must say I'am new at Android but not at Java.
I did HttpRequest With AsyncTask.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {     
        @Override
        public void run() {             
            new RequestTask().execute("http://www.url.com/ajaxrequest/?kategori=27");
        }
    });             
        th.start(); 
}
```

Created Another Class ( Name : RequesTask )

```
class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

private void RequestTask(String URL){

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response;
    // Some Codes Here...

    return responseString;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response;
    String responseString = null;
    // Some Codes Here...

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    // My Result is 'result'
  }
```

I want to send and write this string value to TextView In MainActivty. How can i send 'result' ?
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't open a new thread to run the async task from this thread. It won't work (will fail on internal handler). The async task by himself open for you a new thread.

This is the right code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_text_view);

    new RequestTask().execute("http://www.url.com/ajaxrequest/?kategori=27"); 
}
```

And in your `RequestTask`

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    textView.setText(result);
}
```

**Edit:** To your question, how to access `TextView` from `AsyncTask`
You can do it in many ways. These are part of them:

1. Define `AyncTask` as an inner class inside your `Activity`. You can access members of `Activity` within `AsyncTask`. This option is very coupled, means async task which apparently the logic of your app is part of your ui. Like this:

   ```
   class YouActivity extends Activity { 

       TextView textView;

       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_text_view);

           new RequestTask().execute("http://www.url.com/ajaxrequest/?kategori=27"); 
       }

       class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
           ...
           @Override
           protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
               textView.setText(result);
           }
       } 

   }
   ```
2. Deliver the `TextView` to `AsyncTask` by constructor or setter method. This option is less coupled, since this `AsyncTask` can be used by many consumers who want to update their `TextView`, but the is still coupling by holding reference from `AsyncTask` to your views.
   Your `AsyncTask`:

   ```
   class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

       TextView textView = null;

       public void setTextView(TextView textView) {
           this.textView = textView;
       }

       ...

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
           if (textView != null) {
               textView.setText(result);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   And your activity:

   ```
   class YouActivity extends Activity { 

       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_text_view);

           RequestTask requestTask = new RequestTask();
           requestTask.setTextView(textView);
           requestTask.execute("http://www.url.com/ajaxrequest/?kategori=27"); 
       } 

   }
   ```
3. To make your program more loosely coupled and to make better separation of controller from your views, use `Handler`s:

   ```
   class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

       Handler handler = null;

       public void setHandler(Handler handler) {
           this.handler = handler;
       }

       ...

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
           if (handler != null) {
               Message message = new Message();
       message.obj = result;
               handler.sendMessage(message);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   And your activity:

   ```
   class YouActivity extends Activity { 

       TextView textView;

       Handler handler = new Handler() {
           @Override
           public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                String value = (String) msg.obj;
                textView.setText(value);
           }
       };

       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_text_view);

           RequestTask requestTask = new RequestTask();
           requestTask.setHandler(handler);
           requestTask.execute("http://www.url.com/ajaxrequest/?kategori=27"); 
       } 

   }
   ```

   Handlers cave tons of options. You can 'send message' from any thread and you can decouple your app very good with this tool.

Comment: I made TextView variable as a global member it but doesn't appear in RequestTask
If I define the MainActivity in RequestTask Class and call with somevalue.textView.setText(result); Program fails. And it does not make sense because there is a method as RequestTask() how can i send the variable of TextView to RequestTask's constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You can either pass the TextView to RequestTask's constructor or make it a global member. And in your onPostExecute method:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    yourTextView.setText(result);

}
```

That's it :)

**Edit:** Whoops. As sromku correctly pointed out, AsyncTask already performs the `doInBackground()` method in a separate thread (in background) so you should not be wrapping it in another thread. So, remove that Thread-ception.

Comment: Moved it to complete answer. but +1 from me :)

Answer (score 0):

best solution

Instead of using so many classes for different types of asynctask , I suggest you use this library

you can have a look at here

http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

your code will become very very less , instead of declaring so may asynctask seperately writing bulk of code , you can just use 4 lines of code

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.get("http://www.google.com", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
@Override
public void onSuccess(String response) {
    System.out.println(response);
   }
});
```

I is very efficient in geting the response very quickly.

I hope this will help you out. :)